# How to cleanly process java 8 stream "findFirst()" result even if empty

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

One area that I often finding confusing with java 8 streams is when an intermediate result can be empty, and you need to take alternate paths if it's empty or not empty.

For instance, if I have code like this:

```
String pymtRef = defaultValue;
Optional<PaymentTender> paymentTender = paymentTenders.stream()
        .filter(pt -> (pt.getFlag() == Flag.N || pt.getFlag() == null)).findFirst();
if (paymentTender.isPresent()) {
    pymtRef = paymentTender.get().getId();
}
return pymtRef;
```

I would like to figure out how to remove the conditional block and do this in a single stream.

If I simply call ".map" on the filter result, that can work if it found a matching entry.  If not, I get a NoSuchElementException.

I might instead use "ifPresent()", but the return type of that is "void".

Is there any way to make this cleaner?

**Update**:

The solution using "orElse()" works fine.

The entire method now looks something like this:

```
public String getPaymentReference(OrderContext orderContext) {
    List<PaymentTender> paymentTenders = getPaymentTenders(orderContext);
    if (paymentTenders.size() == 1) {
        return paymentTenders.get(0).getId();
    }
    return paymentTenders.stream()
            .filter(pt -> (pt.getAutoBill() == AutoBill.N || pt.getAutoBill() == null))
            .findFirst().map(pt -> pt.getId()).orElse(DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

Can you think of a way to include the first conditional in the stream without making it more complex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `get()` straight after `map` will yield an exception if the Optional has an empty state, instead call `orElse` after `map` and provide a default value:

```
paymentTenders.stream()
            .filter(pt -> (pt.getFlag() == Flag.N || pt.getFlag() == null))
            .findFirst()
            .map(PaymentTender::getId)
            .orElse(someDefaultValue);
```

**Edit:**

As for:

> Can you think of a way to include the first conditional in the stream
>   without making it more complex?

No, this is better the way you've done it. it's more readable and easier to follow.

introducing any type of logic to make it into one pipeline (*if possible*) will just end of being complex and hence harder to follow and understand.

Comment: Excellent. Updating post with additional refinement of question.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr in all honesty. I'd suggest proceeding with your current approach. see edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one statement via

```
public String getPaymentReference(OrderContext orderContext) {
    List<PaymentTender> paymentTenders = getPaymentTenders(orderContext);
    return paymentTenders.stream()
        .filter(paymentTenders.size() == 1? pt -> true:
                pt -> pt.getAutoBill() == AutoBill.N || pt.getAutoBill() == null)
        .findFirst().map(PaymentTender::getId).orElse(DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

Note that this will not repeat the evaluation of the `paymentTenders.size() == 1` for every element, but use a different function, depending on the state. When the condition is fulfilled, `pt -> true` will accept any element, which will result in the sole element being accepted as intended. Otherwise, the ordinary predicate, `pt -> pt.getAutoBill() == AutoBill.N || pt.getAutoBill() == null` is used.

Comment: Acknowledged. I think in this case I'm going to stick with the slightly more verbose version, but I'll remember this technique of alternate lambdas when it's a better fit.